# Stack Overflow app shows translated human-friendly dates

Tags: bug, android-app, stack-overflow-app

I have a Samsung Galaxy S9 configured in French.

Inside the Stack Overflow app, it appears that human-friendly dates are actually translated in French.

This gives funny half-translated text like

> Asked Il y a 5 jours

or

> Answered Avant-hier

[image: Dates on question][image: Dates on answer]

Comment: got that often in other apps also (including Windows 10), it's pretty annoying. This forces me to read the rest of English text with French accent. "Anseurde avant hier" "Éditède il y a 2 jours"

Comment: If that was the biggest problem with the app, I'd be happy.

Comment: Had to move to the mobile website, app was too bad.

Comment: Answered avec croissant

Comment: @Pac0 **Anseurde avant hier**; I nearly choked on my baguette!

Comment: To get a feeling of how horrible it sounds in our head : https://jsfiddle.net/a62w1f5r/3/ . (if your browser has text-to-speech capabilities, like most desktop ones)

Comment: @Pac0 [Mandatory IT Crowd reference](https://youtu.be/MJXww8aizAM)

Comment: Expect this to be fixed in 6-8 weeks.